# Passing data from Collection View Cell to View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, closures

Here is the `UICollectionViewCell` class:

```
class ViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var lblOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var contentViewOutlet: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

public var dismiss: (()-> Void)? = nil

@IBAction func btnBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss?()
}
}
```

And here is the necessary code scope for the `ViewController` Class:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ViewCell = // Your code to dequeue cell
    cell.dismiss = { [weak self] in
         //??????
    }
}
```

For example, let's assume that I have to pass this data `sender.titleLabel?.text` in to ViewController. So how can I add this parameter(sender.titleLabel?.text) to this code:

```
public var dismiss: (()-> Void)? = nil
```

and How can I read this data in View Controller in below scope:

```
cell.dismiss = { [weak self] in
     //Here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
public var dismiss: ((String)-> Void)? = nil
```

and

```
self.dismiss?(sender.titleLabel!.text)
```

Then

```
cell.dismiss = { [weak self] str  in
    //Here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks but last one gives an error: cell.dismiss = { str [weak self] in
    //Here.
}